# Age is not verifying upon incorrect age detail js validation

Tags: javascript

I have written simple JS program that is validating certain data and it is working correctly.

The problem is that when you type age greater than 100 it shows alert message and that result in error div. It should only print that your information is incorrect.

Meaning, if a user writes age 12 it works perfectly but when user writes 122 or any thing greater than 100 it also shows alert with that 122 in message div. It should reset error div and show only that your information is incorrect.

Here is my code:

```js
function formValidations(){
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
  var job_type    = '';
     
  if(name==''){
    alert('Name required');
  }
     
  if(isNaN(age)||age<1||age>100){
    alert('Enter valid age');
  }
     
  if(!document.getElementById("undergraduate").checked && !document.getElementById("graduate").checked){
    alert('Select Qualification');
  }
     
  if((name=='') && (isNaN(age)||age<1||age>100) && (!document.getElementById("undergraduate").checked || !document.getElementById("graduate").checked)){
    document.getElementById("Info").innerHTML = 'Please correct all details first';
  }
  else if((name!='') && (isNaN(age)||age>1||age<100) && (document.getElementById("undergraduate").checked || document.getElementById("graduate").checked)){
    document.getElementById("Info").innerHTML = 'Hello <b>'+name+'<b><br>';
    document.getElementById("Info").innerHTML += 'Your age is '+age+' Years<br>';
   if(document.getElementById("undergraduate").checked){
    document.getElementById("Info").innerHTML += 'Your Qualification is '+document.getElementById("undergraduate").value+'<br>';
   }
   else if(document.getElementById("graduate").checked){
    document.getElementById("Info").innerHTML += 'Your Qualification is '+document.getElementById("graduate").value+'<br>';
   }
   if(document.getElementById("it").checked){
    job_type += 'Job1 : '+document.getElementById("it").value+'<br>';  
   }
   else{
    job_type += 'Job1 : None<br>';
   }
   if(document.getElementById("marketing").checked){
    job_type += 'Job2 : '+document.getElementById("marketing").value+'<br>'; 
   }
   else{
    job_type += 'Job2 : None<br>';
   }
   if(document.getElementById("academics").checked){
    job_type += 'Job3 : '+document.getElementById("academics").value+'<br>'; 
   }
   else{
    job_type += 'Job3 : None<br>';
   }
   document.getElementById("Info").innerHTML += 'Your selected Job Types are <br>'+job_type+'<br>';
  }
 }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Pre Assesment Task 2</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> Online Job Portal </h1>
    <form>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Name:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="Name" size="20" id="name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Age:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="Age" size="20" id="age"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Qualification:</td>
          <td>Under Graduate:
            <input type="radio" name="qualification"  Value="Undergraduate" id="undergraduate">
            Graduate:
            <input type="radio" name="qualification" Value="Graduate" id="graduate"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Select a Job Type:</td>
          <td>IT:
            <input type="checkbox" name="jobtype"  Value="IT" id="it">
            Marketing:
            <input type="checkbox" name="jobtype" Value="Marketing" id="marketing">
            Academics:
            <input type="checkbox" name="jobtype" Value="Academics" id="academics"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><div id="Info"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="button" name="Show Information" value="Show Information" onClick="formValidations()"></td>
          <td><input type="reset" name="Reset Form" value="Reset Form"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding a return statement before the alert, assuming you just want to bail. This stops the execution of the function. Add it in the second if statement, where you check the age.

Comment: That would let you remove any other 'age' conditionals in the code, as they would no longer apply. It could clean up some of your other stuff. Remember that your entire function will still execute until you return something. So if it happens to satisfy another conditional somewhere further down the function, then that code will execute

Comment: This didn't help me.

Comment: Also, good practice to load the javascript AFTER the html. One sec, I'll make a bin

Comment: here's the bin https://jsbin.com/noxugumize/edit?html,output

Comment: Is that what you are looking for? I just added the return statement, now if you enter an invalid age, it will alert and then stop the rest of the function. Without printing the results

Comment: No, this is not what I am looking for. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: I simply wants to see if alert comes up, the whole error div should reset and only shows "Please correct all details first"

Comment: Hmm. I don't see any error div's in the code? Also i don't see the message "please correct all details first"? maybe I'm blind? I'm not sure what functionality you are seeking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You should replace this line***

```
else if((name!='') && (isNaN(age)||age>1||age<100) && (document.getElementById("undergraduate").checked || document.getElementById("graduate").checked))
```

***with this line***

```
else if((name!='') && (!isNaN(age) && age>1 && age<100) && (document.getElementById("undergraduate").checked || document.getElementById("graduate").checked))
```

I guess this is what you are probably looking for.

Comment: didin't get what you actually meant? Could you please elaborate

Comment: so my last comment didn't make much sense. but a condition like this would be more useful

    `age = parseInt(value); // to check for either NaN or a valid integer`
    `if (age && age < 100) // valid age`
    `else if ( age > 100 ) // invalid condition 1`
    `else // invalid age ( NaN or 0 )`

p.s , sorry for messed up code. Can somebody post this comment as properly indented code.

Comment: @wannabeApro yes, that is an approach. JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tsnbfea4/4/
but that won't make much difference I guess.

Comment: it won't per say, but when dealing with integer values such as age, it is better to narrow down the scope to either number or NaN. Not to mention, valid conditions can be then only restricted to check `if (age && age < 100)` for validation.